# Iterating over a Django QuerySet while deleting objects in the same QuerySet

Tags: python, django, loops, django-queryset

I am wondering what is the best way to iterate over a Django QuerySet while deleting objects within the Queryset? For example, say you have a log table with entries at specific times, and you wanted to archive them so that there is no more than 1 entry every 5 minutes. I know this may be wrong, but this is kind of what I am going for:

```
toarchive = Log.objects.all().order_by("-date")
start = toarchive[0].date
interval = start - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
for entry in toarchive[1:]:        
    if entry.date > interval:
        entry.delete()
    else:
        interval = entry.date - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
```

Comment: This is valid, you can delete the objects that way.

Comment: Using delete() when looping on queryset like that, keep an empty reccord when I go to the admin page of the model. It seems the object is not entirely deleted. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 7):

So I guess I have answered my own question by asking it, if anyone else is curious. I thought there would have been a problem when deleting objects while iterating over them, but there isn't. The code snippet in the question is the right way to do it.

Comment: How can I remove the element from the query set instead of deleting the object after I have performed the filter operation?

Answer (score 1):

Querysets have a `delete` method that will delete all the results of that queryset. For the example you gave

```
toarchive.filter(date__gt=interval).delete()
```

will work. If you're doing a test that can't be done in a filter, however, the method you described is probably best.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I know that this method is possible too. However in this case I don't think that will work, because the delete condition is relative between entries in the QuerySet. I guess what I want to know more generally is, will I run into problems if I am deleting objects from the QuerySet, while I iterate through it.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't paying attention to the `else` clause there. I haven't tested it, but deleting objects in a QuerySet should be safe, because `delete` only issues the SQL delete query, it doesn't affect the model object in memory.

Comment: will this destroy the database entry? or just remove it from the queryset?

Comment: @halilpazarlama, this will delete the object from database permanently

Comment: Yeah, I was looking the other way around. But apparently (as far as i see) in Django it's not very common to manipulate queryset objects after obtaining them.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the core of his question. If you need to do processing for a non-trivial filter condition, you need to delete while iterating.